# Addressing UK magistrate as "My Lord"

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-terms, judge

Is it legal to call a magistrate “My lord”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn’t illegal, it’s just wrong.

The correct way to [address](https://www.judiciary.uk/you-and-the-judiciary/what-do-i-call-judge/) a magistrate in a UK court is “Your Worship” or “Sir/Madam”.

“My Lord/Lady” is only for HIgh Court judges and above.